# How can I diagnose why a website signs-out when cookies are enabled?

Tags: firefox, debian, cookies

I running Firefox ESR 52.x with cookies enabled (details below) on a Debian-based system. When I close my browser and re-open it most websites, including Super User, "remember" me. A handful do not, although I can see that they have left cookies.

At least one site suggests that it *should* be remembered. How can I diagnose why it is not?

Cookie settings:

- Accept cookies
- Keep until they expire
- Reject third-party cookies

Other privacy settings:

- Remember my browsing and download history
- Do not remember search and form history
- Do not clear history when browser exits
- Always apply Do Not Track
- Use Disconnect.me basic protection

(It's not clear to me if the DNT and Disconnect.me settings apply in non-private browsing.)

Comment: Try to enable 3rd party cookies and see if it helps

Comment: Its possible a cookie is set but is corrupt. A new cookie by that name is ignored and that may seem that it doesn't work. Clearing your cookies is a way to resolve those issues.

Comment: Banking sites do not keep the session. Can you add examples of the sites that do not keep the session alive?

Answer (score 1):

My suspition is that the session cookies by those website are marked HttpOnly due to which firefox does not persist the cookies in local disk and therefore is not able to reload them when firefox restarts. Can you check for the same behavior on any other browser ? You can check for the HttpOnly flag by inspecting the header.

Comment: I'll try this, if this is the case would that suggest that Stack Exchange sites do NOT set HttpOnly?